# Debug into compiled DLL files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a third-party DLL (CSLA) which is referenced withing my project. Now it all works OK, but when there is an exception thrown from CSLA for whatever reason, it shows the disassembly with the memory addresses etc. I would like to actually see the source code. I have done the following and still no difference.

1. Disable debugging in my just my code option in Visual Studio 2010.
2. Check the symbol files are being loaded ( Debug --> Windows --> Modules) and seems as though they are.

Is my assumption correct that as long as there is .pdb file being loaded then I should be able to debug into source code?

Why can't I get the debugger to show the source code?

Comment: you want to show source code of a dll file?

Comment: Yes, just want the debugger to break at the correct exception line.

Answer (score 2):

No. The .pdb alone does not include the source code. It's just a mapping file for IL-location => source code line.

[.NET Reflector Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) (the non-freeversion) enables you to step into external libraries code.

Comment: Thanks, that at least gives me more info about what the purpose of the pdb's purpose. Please see my answer about the issue im having with with .net reflector pro.

Comment: I've even debug into Sharepoint.dll this thing is really amazing :) If you want to see some amazing code style do try this one ... am sure you won't regret :)

Comment: Yeah would be nice but since it can't decompile guess pro Reflector is not great for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Actually pdb file will not guarantee that you will be able to step through the source code. PDBs contains informations about locations of sources, so you have to get the sources to do such debugging. One thing you can do is to use Debug -> Exceptions option. You have to check box with exception you obtain (or add a new one) and debug your application. Next time you will brake at the moment of throwing exception and you will be able to collect stack traces.

Comment: I should add I have done this and it does break at the exception, but as mentioned, only shows me the memory addresses.

Comment: Yes, but without sources (and with pdb) you can only collect stack traces - sometimes it is enough to find out the cause of exception.

Comment: Thanks, it does help my understanding of the purpose of a pdb file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the source code for the 3rd party DLL?  If not, then that's why you can't see it.

The paid-for version of Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) can debug into 'decompiled' code, which is often surprisingly clear.   This only works if the DLL you're having a problem with is a .NET assembly, which I'm not 100% certain it is from your question.

Comment: OK, I tried this and since the pdb file already exists within the directory I had to rename it. However reflector still errors at the decompilation stage.